# Zenity Progress Bar

Tags: shell-script, zenity

I made a shell script which uses this command to calculate a sha256 checksum recursive for a directory for example `/run/media/$USER/directory`:

```
find . -type f -exec sha256sum {} \; | sort -k 2 | sha256sum
```

This process takes some time. Meanwhile I want to display a progress bar via **zenity** that shows the current progress according to the command.
I tried it with:

```
find . -type f -exec sha256sum {} \; | sort -k 2 | sha256sum | zenity --progress --title="Checksum"
```

but it doesn't show any percentages:

[image]

Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Please tell us more about your dataset. Eg: `find . -type f |   parallel -X du | perl -ane '$F[0]=~s/\S/9/g; print $F[0],"\n"'| sort -n | uniq -c`

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f |
  parallel --bar sha256sum {} 2> >(perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/="\r";$|=1};s/\r/\n/g' |
    zenity --progress --auto-kill) |
  sort -k 2 | sha256sum
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn´t seem to work :/  . 
The progress bar is always at 100%.

Comment: @stewie I think you need to tell us more about your dataset.